# MySQL 5.7 fastest way to select latest from join

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, aggregate-functions

Currently I'm using this query to get all products with the latest price and stock from the prices table:

```
SELECT 
    products.*, 
    prices.price AS latest_price, 
    prices.stock AS latest_stock
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN prices ON prices.id = (
    SELECT id 
    FROM prices 
    WHERE prices.product_id = products.id AND prices.created_at >= '2018-08-18 00:00:00' 
    ORDER BY created_at DESC 
    LIMIT 1
)
WHERE products.shop_id = 1
```

**[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fSq6W1ZwfB1FeAxCisxRHv/0)**

But this is slow with a lot of products (millions) and a lot of prices (billions). How can I improve this query? In general joins are faster, but can this achieved with joins? I'm trying with:

```
SELECT
    ANY_VALUE(products.id),
    ANY_VALUE(products.name),
    prices.price, -- Which aggregate function to use?
    MAX(prices.created_at)
FROM products
LEFT JOIN prices ON prices.product_id = products.id AND prices.created_at >= '2018-08-22 00:00:00'
WHERE shop_id = 3
GROUP BY products.id
```

But now I've to specify all product columns and wrap `ANY_VALUE()` around it? And the `MAX()` is selecting the latest `created_at` date from the prices but how can I select the `price` from the same row?

Comment: which index you have on the table  prices and products ??

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: the  first query seemns return all the product but linked to one price only  you are scanning nillion of rows for get one row only but anyway you scan entire table for this  (limit 1 return just one rows  and you join this row with all the others  ..) is not clear to me   you should add   a proper data sample, the tables  schema and the expcted  result  ..

Comment: @scaisEdge and Strawberry, I've added a DB Fiddle. Indexes are included as well.